# Routing issue: Getting routed to a wrong view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple application (http://myurl.com) and when I type the url in the address bar, I get routed to http://myurl.com/RBA/Login.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!loginSuccessful)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
            else 
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyTickets");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
            ViewBag.Message = "An error occurred";
            throw;
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

However, after I login to the application and when I type `http://myurl.com`, I get an error page with the following message:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/MyTickets/Index.cshtml
~/Views/MyTickets/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I put a break point on the Index action in MyTicketsController and I was able to hit my breakpoint but getting the same error message. To fix this issue, i copied the MyTickets folder under Views in RBA area and pasted this inside the common Views folder and it worked.

My question here is why am I directed to the wrong view? I know this has something to do with the routing and I would appreciate any insight into this problem. Thanks

This is my routes:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "RBA_default",
        "RBA/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: how are you routes set up? is `RBA` an area?

Comment: Yes RBA is an area

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that `MyTickets/Index.cshtml` does not exist in the root view folder.
If your `MyTickets` controller is in an area you need to specify the area when you do the redirect.

Try adding the area name when calling the redirect method.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyTickets", new { area = "YourArea" });
```